# Content overlays my footer

Tags: php, html, overlay

I can't get my footer to show below all my content. The content currently overlays anything right at the bottom and I can't fix it.

Footer code:

```
</div> <!-- end #content -->
</div> <!-- end #container -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>


<div id="footer" width:100%; >

<div id="column" style="width: 100%; height:200px; background-color:none;">
    <div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#cdbfc9; ">
        <div style="width:80%; height:80px; background-color:#fefefe;  margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px;">
            <!--Information for left column content starts here-->
            <h6>LATEST NEWS</h6>

        </div><!--Information for left column content ends here -->
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. The URL is:

Comment: Where is the URL? although the question should be written so that we do not need it

Comment: div id=footer not closed in you example